# CSV -(excel)- Python. Seems like wrong writing on csv from python

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I´m trying to export some data from a website and I first tried on one single page. I´ve to import text delimited by titles:
['Drug name','General Information','Clinical Results','Side Effects','Mechanism of Action','Literature
References','Additional Information','Approval Date','Date Created','Company Name']

The url is https://www.centerwatch.com/directories/1067-fda-approved-drugs/listing/3092-afinitor-everolimus

The code currently works, it gives me all the data. But when I insert it on the CSV , the information is not delimited as I wish.
As it is one single page, the excel should have ONE row... but it doesn´t

The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

csv_file = open('Drugs.csv','w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter ='+')
csv_writer.writerow(['Drug name','General Information','Clinical Results','Side Effects','Mechanism of Action','Literature References','Additional Information','Approval Date','Date Created','Company Name'])

link = requests.get('https://www.centerwatch.com/directories/1067-fda-approved-drugs/listing/3092-afinitor-everolimus')
aux =[]

soup = BeautifulSoup(link.content, 'lxml')
drugName = soup.find('div', class_='company-navigation').find('h1').text
gralInfo = soup.find('div', class_='body directory-listing-profile__description')
y = 0
for h2 in gralInfo.find_all('h2'):
    print (y)
    text =''
    for sibling in h2.find_next_siblings():
        if (sibling.name == 'h2'):
            break
        else:
            text = text + sibling.get_text(separator ='\n') + '\n'
    print(text)
    aux.append(text)
    print()
    print()
    y = y + 1


auxi = []
for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='contact directory-listing-profile__master-detail'):
    print(info.text)
    auxi.append(info.text)
 
csv_writer.writerow([drugName, aux[0], aux[1], aux[2], aux[3], aux[4], aux[5], auxi[0], auxi[1], auxi[2]])
```

[image: Here, we can see the wrong delimitation that i get]

Comment: try removing `delimeter='+'` and dont forget to close your csv file

Comment: I could fix it!. I change the delimiter from "+" to ";" and then it worked! 
thanks for the intention